# Issue with nested promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have nested asyc await function call as shown below.i am not able to pass the return from the first promise to the next one. What is the issue with the below code?

```
const ret = ProductRepository.getProductsBySameBrand(brand);
        ret.then(function (result) {
            shuffle(result.items).then(function (result) {
                console.log(result) //console is printing proper output
                return result; // This is not returning anything to the next chain
            });
        }).then(function (result) {
               // result is undefined
            context.setState({ products: result });
        });
```

Comment: You need to return the call to `shuffle`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something, but can't you move the `constext.setState` up to the previous promise?

```
const ret = ProductRepository.getProductsBySameBrand(brand);
        ret.then(function (result) {
            shuffle(result.items).then(function (result) {
                console.log(result) //console is printing proper output
                context.setState({ products: result }); // <-- move here
            });
        }); // <-- delete extra .then()
```